# How can I detect the name of a file angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am using this module for angular:
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload
This is my code which works:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
     <td>
         <strong ng-model="test">{{ item.file.name }}</strong>
         <!-- Image preview -->
         <!--auto height-->
         <!--<div ng-thumb="{ file: item.file, width: 100 }"></div>-->
         <!--auto width-->
         <div ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" ng-thumb="{ file: item._file, height: 200 }"></div>
         <!--fixed width and height -->
         <!--<div ng-thumb="{ file: item.file, width: 100, height: 100 }"></div>-->
     </td>
     <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item.file.size/1024/1024|number:2 }} MB</td>
     <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
         <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
             <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }"></div>
         </div>
     </td>
     <td class="text-center">
         <span ng-show="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
         <span ng-show="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>
         <span ng-show="item.isError"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
     </td>
     <td nowrap>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="item.upload()" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
          </button>
                                   
     </td>
</tr>
```

How can I extract the name of the file without the extension?

Answer (score 0):

What about substring? Something like:

```
var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
```

And to get extension:

```
var ext =  item._file.substr(item._file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Comment: yes it works .but I want to keep that value of ext in rooscope.